# Changing values when using elements of a list in arithmatic using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

While coding I noticed that values of elements of a 2D list of floats which I was using were changing after including them in a division.

```
import random

centroids = [[] for _ in range(3)]

maxes = []
mins = []

maxes.append(5)
mins.append(2)
maxes.append(10)
mins.append(4)
maxes.append(20)
mins.append(8)
maxes.append(40)
mins.append(16)

for i in range(0, 4):
    centroids[0].append(round(random.uniform(mins[i], maxes[i]), 4))
    centroids[1].append(centroids[0][i])
    while centroids[1][i] == centroids[0][i]:
        centroids[1][i] = round(random.uniform(mins[i], maxes[i]), 4)

    centroids[2].append(centroids[1][i])
    while centroids[2][i] == centroids[1][i]:
        centroids[2][i] = round(random.uniform(mins[i], maxes[i]), 4)


totals = list(centroids)

totals[0][0] = totals[0][0] + 10
print(totals[0][0])
centroids[0][0] = totals[0][0] / 2
print(totals[0][0])
```

An example of the output the print gives is:

```
13.7442
6.8721
```

The problem is that the value of totals[0][0] is changing when I use it to calculate the value of centroids[0][0].

Am I missing something obvious as to why this is happening?

Comment: Please Paste Full code Here.

Comment: What's wrong with `6.106930681000604` and `0.12463123838776742`?

Comment: Sorry about that. Changed the post to include a full example.

Comment: Looks like a shallow copy situation.

Comment: You need to make a deep-copy

Comment: deepcopy worked. Thanks guys :)